# Order of convergence of the Newton method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, numerical-calculus

I have a problem with this exercise.

Let a function $f∈C^{p+1}(\mathbb{R})$ be given. let f have a p-fold root in $x^∗$, $p ∈ N$.

Now consider the following variant of Newton's method to determine $x^∗$:

$x_{n+1}=x_{n}-p·\frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})} \text{ for } n=0,1,2,...$.

Determine the local order of convergence of the iteration procedure.

I really don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to show that $g'(z)=0$, where $g(x)= x- p\cdot \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ and $z$ is the solution of the equation. Since $z$ is a root with order $p$, we know that $f(x) = (x-z)^p \phi(x)$, where $\phi(z)\ne 0$. Use this to show that $\lim_{x\to z} g'(x)=0$.

---

If the sequence $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$ converges to $z$ and
$$
g'(z)=g''(z)=\cdots =g^{(p-1)}(z), \quad g^{(p)}(z)\ne 0
$$
you can conclude that it converges with order $p$. This is a direct consequence of Taylor's formula:
$$
g(x_n) = g(z) + g'(z)(x_n-z) + \cdots + \frac{g^{(p-1)}(z)}{(p-1)!}(x_n-z)^{p-1} + \frac{g^{(p)}(\xi_n)}{p!}(x_n-z)^p.
$$

Noting that $g(z)=z$, $x_{n+1} = g(x_n)$, and that the derivatives of $g$ at $z$ are zero up to the order $p-1$, the previous expression becomes
$$
|x_{n+1}-z| = \dfrac{|g^{(p)}(\xi_n)|}{p!} |x_n -z|^p,
$$

which establishes convergence with order $p$.

Comment: I don't follow -- if $z$ is a root of order $p$, then certainly $f'(z)=0$, and hence $g(z)$ is **undefined**.

Comment: @Zim If you are able to compute $\lim_{x\to z} g(z)$ you can use this limit as a definition for $g(z)$. In a way, $x=z$ is a removable singularity. The same goes for $g'(z)$.